# Why can't classes that use EJB @Schedule be abstract Classes?

Tags: java, ejb, scheduled-tasks

I need to schedule a task and I'm using EJB @Schedule to do so. It's working fine, however I thought I might try to generalize my design so that I can extend from some abstract scheduler, inherit certain functionality, and specify additional functionality in the sub classes extending the abstract class. This way, when I need additional schedulers that perform similar actions, I don't have to rewrite a bunch of code. I wrote it, didn't get any errors, and I thought all was well, and then when I tried to restart my server,
I got:

`EJB class com.schedule.SubmissionScheduler must not be defined as abstract : mcftEAR#mcftWeb.war#SubmissionSchedule` in the console.

Maybe I don't know enough about how the @Schedule annotation works, but I can't think of any reason abstract classes won't be allowed for this. Any insight would be appreciated

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Schedule;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;


public abstract class SubmissionScheduler {


  public abstract SubmissionScheduler getInstance();

  @Schedule(hour= "0")
  public void every24Hours() {
    // Pull all forms and submit every 24 hours
    List<Form> forms = getFormsThatAreReadyForSubmission();

    // Loop through the list of forms and submit
    if (forms != null  || !forms.isEmpty()) {
      for (Form form : forms) {
        form.getFormDao().submit());
      }
    }
}
```

...Then I have another class which extends this one.

EDIT: In addition to not being able to make it an abstract class, it won't allow for the class to be final either...Why??

Comment: What EJB container is this?

Comment: Remove the `@Stateless` from your abstract base class because it is not an EJB (which cannot be abstract). Add the `@Stateless` to your concrete subclasses instead.

Comment: @SteveC got it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need an instance of your bean to run any function - in your case scheduled function.

It is impossible to run a function from abstract class cause it's abstract - a container cannot create instance to run your code. So it have to be non abstract to create instance and run a method.

Comment: The Scheduler would be a member/attribute of my bean, so would not need to instantiate it. The bean would instead instantiate a subclass that extends the Scheduler. Not trying to 'write off' your answer, I just don't understand how what you stated could be the reason. Also, removing `abstract` and making it final also is not allowed.